# Mechanics dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

A schematic diagram of a part of Whit
worth quick-return mechanisnm
Crank OA of radius 0.2 m rotates in clockwise, about fixed O , at a uniform angular velocity of OA is 10 rad/s. The crank end is A is pivoted  a slider which slides in slotted lever AQ pivoted at fixed point Q as shown.
For the configuration of the mechanism given, crank the horizontal angle of 60° to horizontal and the slotted lever is perpendicular to the crank radius.

(a)
Use Gruebler's equation to assess, based on the overall number of degrees of freedom,
the viability of the system as a kinematic link mechanism. Choose the appropriate
elements with labels I-fixed members), 2-(crank), 3-(slider), and 4-(slotted lever).

(b)
Skecth the velocity diagram for the instant shown and determine the angular velocity of
the slotted lever and the sliding velocity between the slider and the slotted lever. Take the point on the slotted lever as A' coinciding with pivot point A on the slider and the crank.

c) Sketch the acceleration diagram for the given configuration. Determine the angular acceleration of slotted lever AQ and the linear acceleration of its centre of mass G positioned 0.3 m from Q.
[image]

Comment: To garner a good response here, could you add your efforts in attempting the question?

Comment: I try to draw the velocity diagram. when the slotted lever is perpendicular to the crank radius aa' is zero. There is only one line in velocity diagram. so how to find the angular velocity of the slotted lever. is it zero??

Comment: Please read the [homework and exercise](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) policy for physics stack exchange.  Note that we focus on conceptual questions, and any question here should clearly show effort and ask a conceptual question about what you are having trouble with.